# Using SemanticUI with Docker

Tags: node.js, express, docker, dockerfile, semantic-ui

I setted up a Docker container running an express app. Here is the dockerfile :

FROM node:latest

```
# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install --global gulp
RUN npm i gulp

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "nodemon", "-L", "./bin/www" ]
```

As you can see, it uses the nodejs image and creates an app folder in my container, itself containing my application. IThe docker container, on start runs npm install and installs my modules on the container (thanks to that i don't have this node_modules folder in my local folder) i want to integrate SemanticUI which uses gulp. I so installed gulp on my container but the files created by semantic are only present on my container. They are not on my local folder. How can i dynamically make that those files created on my container are locally present to modify.

---

I thought that one of docker's great jobs was to not have node_modules installed on your local app folder .. maybe i am wrong if so please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) to share files with the container and host machine.

Something like this:

```
docker run ... -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container ...
```

or if you are using docker-compose, see [volume configuration reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference).

```
...
volumes:
  - /path/on/host:/path/in/container
```